# Offset internal temperature

Tags: 13.10, fan

Using "Hardware Sensors Indicator," I determined that, even when sitting in a room at room temperature (~75-78 degrees F) it thought that my temperature internally is 136. This can't be right. It doesn't even feel warm.

Even when starting from an overnight shutdown, the fan runs and continually gets faster, most likely because what it *thinks* is the internal temperature.

How do I fix this?

Comment: What does the BIOS show for temperature? What CPU?

Answer (score 0):

Thats not room temperature , that's the temperature of your CPU. Processor will get heated after you start working with that.  You can get CPU, GPU temparature by using those sensors.

Comment: Yes, but this is right after startup. I get when it's been going for a while, but really? Does it get heatedd that fast?

Comment: Yes you know what,  I have two fans to cool my CPU and HDD

Comment: Adding an extra fan at the CPU can help you to low.

Comment: Yeah but I don't have that option. Ubuntu is running on a laptop.

Comment: Okay, but laptops have some cooling pads. Cost of 10$ or 500 rupees.you can have one.